# maven build failure - maven dependencies could not be resolved

Tags: java, maven

While downloading maven dependencies I'm getting the below error

```
 Plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.7.RELEASE or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:2.1.7.RELEASE: 
Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:pom:2.1.7.RELEASE from/to mdcm 
(https://example.aaa.bbb.com:8443/example/repository/MDCM): unexpected end of stream on Connection
{example.aaa.bbb.com:8443, proxy=HTTP @ aaa.bbb.ccc.com/1.1.1.1:8080 hostAddress=1.1.1.1 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} 
(recycle count=0): \n not found: size=0 content=... -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

My `pom.xml`

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.dbs</groupId>
        <artifactId>credit-card</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>credit-card</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    
        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.2</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        </properties>
    
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        
         <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>mdcm</id>
                <url>https://example.aaa.bbb.com:8443/example/repository/MDCM</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>https://example.aaa.bbb.com:8443/example/content/repositories/dbsrepo</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>mirror</id>
                <url>https://example.aaa.bbb.com:8443/example/repository/TDIN_RMT</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories> 
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>mdcm</id>
                <url>https://example.aaa.bbb.com:8443/example/repository/MDCM</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    
    </project>
```

Comment: Can you find the artifact in your nexus ?

Comment: Network/firewall/proxy issue: `sitory/MDCM): unexpected end of stream on Connection`...Furthermore do not define repositories in pom file better using settings.xml for configuration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your nexus server is connected to internet, make sure a proxy to maven central is properly configured. Refer to [this](https://blog.sonatype.com/using-nexus-3-as-your-repository-part-1-maven-artifacts) page for documentation on how to setup a proxy.

If you nexus server is **not** connected to internet, you have to manually upload all artifacts to your nexus repository before using them in your projects.